# No hallo el error de mi código en PHP utilizando la librería PDO

Tags: php

Estoy programando en `PHP` utilizando la librería `PDO` pero me sale un Error

Conexion.php:

```
<?php

class Conexion {

       function Conectar(){
            try{
                $servidor = "localhost";
                $user = "root";
                $pass = "";
                $db = "bdejemplos";
                $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=$db",$user,$pass);
                echo 'conectado';

            }  catch (Exception $e){
                echo 'Error '. $e->getMessage();
            }
           return $con; 
    }
}

?>
```

OpClientes.php

```
<?php
include './Conexion.php';
//include_once '../entidades/Clientes.php';

class OpClientes {

    function NCodigo() {

        $con = new Conexion();
        $con->Conectar();        
        //$cli = new Clientes();        
        //$sql = "call bdejemplos.IdCliente(?)";
        $sql = "SELECT nom FROM `clientes where id = ?";
        $consulta = $con->prepare($sql);
        if ($consulta->execute(array('miguel'))) {
            while ($fila = $consulta->fetch()) {
                echo "$fila";
            }
        }
    }

}

$c = new OpClientes();
$c->NCodigo();

?>
```

Error al Compilar:

> ```
> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Conexion::prepare() in 
>  C:\xampp\htdocs\ejemplos\Modelos\OpClientes.php on line 14
> ```

Bueno ese es el error que me sale cuando compilo el `Script OpClientes`

Comment: Aunque no está relacionado directamente, hay un error en la sentencia SQL, falta una \` al final de "clientes": `SELECT nom FROM \`clientes\` where id = ?`

Comment: ¿Puedes poner tu archivo `Conexion.php`? El erro que te da es que no tienes el método `prepare` en tu clase `Conexion`

Comment: Cambia `$con->Conectar();` por `$conn = $con->Conectar();` || Y también cambia `$con->prepare($sql);` por `$conn->prepare($sql);`

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema está justo aquí:

```
$con->Conectar();
```

Deberías de guardar el resultado de esa llamada en `$con` de nuevo teniendo en cuenta que ese método devuelve la conexión a la base de datos:

```
$con = $con->Conectar();
```

El error da porque en el momento de llamar a `prepare()`, lo estás haciendo sobre tu objeto y no sobre el objeto PDO que devuelve el método `Conectar()`

Comment: Como seria la sintaxis entonces disculpa que te diga eso es que soy nuevo en PDO

Comment: Cambiando la línea a `$con = $con->Conectar();` debería de funcionar. A no ser que tengas un error de conexión a la base de datos, claro.

Comment: me salió ahora este Error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function Conectar() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejemplos\Modelos\OpClientes.php on line 9Fatal error: Call to undefined function Conectar() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejemplos\Modelos\OpClientes.php on line 9

Comment: ¿Puedes hacer un `var_dump($con);` justo antes de `$con = $con->Conectar();`?